# Ignore rows with NULL join columns in hive query

Tags: sql, hive, null

I have three tables A, B and C.  A is having 1 billion records,  B is having 10 million records and C is having 5 million records. 
My query is like

`select * 
   from tableA a 
       left outer join tableB b on a.id=b.id 
       left outer join tableC c on b.id=c.id;`

After first join i will be having more than 990 million NULL b.id columns. Now the second join on table C will require all 990 million NULL rows (b.Id) to be processed and this causes one reducer to be loaded for a very long time.  Is there a way i can avoid rows with NULL  join columns?

Comment: Why can't you just use inner joins?

Comment: Why do you think  reducer works very long time because of those NULLS? have you read the logs?

Comment: @leftjoin Reducer is copying all the NULL rows (990 million),  sorts it,  and then doing the reduce operation.

Comment: @cloud actually my query has subsequent joins on to table A.

Comment: See updated answer please

Answer (score 2):

We have used rand() for NULL ; so our join condition will be

`coalesce(b.id, rand()) = c.id`

Thus null values got distributed by its own, but i am wondering why the skewjoin settings didnot help (we have tried coalesce(b.id, 'SomeString') = c.id with skewjoin enable )

Answer (score 1):

Add `b.id is not null` condition to the ON clause. Depending on your Hive version this may help:

```
select * 
   from tableA a 
       left outer join tableB b on a.id=b.id 
       left outer join tableC c on b.id=c.id and b.id is not null;
```

But this is not a problem since 0.14 version as far as I know.

Also you can divide null rows and not null and join only not null rows.
In the first query only null rows selected. Add NULL as col for columns from C table. Then use UNION ALL + select all not null rows:

```
with a as(
select a.*, b.* 
   from tableA a 
       left outer join tableB b on a.id=b.id
)

select a.*, null as c_col1 --add all other columns(from c) as null to get same schema
   from a where a.b_id_col is null
UNION ALL
select a.*, c.*
   left outer join tableC c on a.b_id_col=c.id
   from a where a.b_id_col is not null
```

Comment: we have tried this but no luck.  Using CDH 5.9 with hive 1. 20

Comment: "is not null" check in join condition is not working. Anyidea why?  CDH 5.9,  hive 1.1.0

Comment: Second approach will,  we have tried that. But we have similar joins in the same query (our query has around 60+ joins) and first would be our  preferred solution. Now what we understood is that we wont able to avoid those null values (b.id) since those rows has values for a.id which is our driving table.  So we are working on to enable skew join but data still goes to one reducer.

Comment: @Despicableme Try to add `distribute by` by some field to force distribution not by b.id

Comment: @leftjoinsorry for the late reply. We have used similar approach, we have used rand() for NULL ; so our join condition will be

coalesce(b.id, rand()) = c.id

Thus null values got distributed by its own, but i am wondering why the skewjoin settings didnot help (we have tried coalesce(b.id, 'SomeString') = c.id with skewjoin enable )

Comment: @Despicableme skewjoin settings do not work for me as well in Hive 1.2